# No Google folder under Administrative Templates via Group Policy editor - Adding GoogleUpdate.adm does nothing

Tags: group-policy, templates, gpedit, google-updates

I'm unable to complete "Step 2" :

*Step 2. Importing Google Update ADM template.
Navigate to Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates
Right-click Administrative Templates, and select Add/Remove Templates
Add the GoogleUpdate.adm template via the dialog.
Once complete, a Google folder will appear under 'Administrative Templates' if it's not there already.*

Initially I got the error message that GoogleUpdate.adm was invalid and or too long.   Then I redownloaded it and added it again, and now nothing happens.  When I add/open GoogleUpdate.adm, I click Open and then it just goes back to the previous screen, without adding a "Google folder".

Not sure what to do.  Any help is very much appreciated.  Thank you.

Edit:  My original problem is this -

*Update failed (error: 7)An error occurred while checking for updates: Google Chrome cannot be updated due to inconsistent Google Update Group Policy settings. Use the Group Policy Editor to set the update policy override for the Google Chrome Binaries application and try again; see http://goo.gl/uJ9gV for details.*

Edit #2:

Fixed original problem by doing this:

*If you get the chrome update error message (Update Failed Error:7) above so you can’t update, Follow this simple steps below to solve the issue.
Step 01. Go to Windows Start Button on the left bottom and Click on Run.
Step 02. Type in regedit on the run.
Step 03. go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update
Step 04. Delete these two values below.
- Update{8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}
- Update{8BA986DA-5100-405E-AA35-86F34A02ACBF}
Step 06. Restart your Chrome Browser and try to update again.
You are done! GOOD JOB!*

Except I only deleted the first value because I didn't have the second one.  Now Google is, finally, up-to-date.

I still do not get a "Google folder" in the Group Policy editor when I add the ADM template.  That problem seems sorta moot now, but I still would like to figure it out, if anyone knows how.  Thanks.